# Is there a way to specify order of results manually in SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I have a PHP array of IDs of rows to retrieve from a MySQL database.

```
$ids = array(35, 20, 1, 5);
```

Is there any way I could construct an SQL query that retrieves a resource from the database with rows in that specific order of IDs?

In other words, the list of rows returned would have row with ID 35 first, then the row with ID of 20, and so on.

Comment: Why don't you fix the sort order in PHP when you got the result back?

Comment: I have a javascript list of IDs of recently viewed pages. This is stored in cookies in individual browsers. I then use AJAX to grab these objects, and it would be great to preserve the order in which the pages were viewed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?php
$ids = array(35, 20, 1, 5);
$q = 'select * from table where id in ('.implode(',',$ids).') order by find_in_set(id, \''.implode(',',$ids).'\')' ;
```

Comment: +1, I was going to answer to use `field()`, but `find_in_set()` is nicer because you could easily supply the list using a prepared statement and bound parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Sorting on PHP/Javascript end would be easier, but one way comes to mind how you could do it in SQL:

```
select * from whatever where id in (35,20,1,5) order by
case id when 35 then 0 when 20 then 1 when 1 then 2 when 5 then 3 end
```

Comment: Use `ORDER BY CASE`. Doing a bunch of `UNION`s is not preferred.

Comment: @Michael - That was my first thought too, but then I thought - is MySQL smart enough to optimize "id in (const list)" to 4 fetches by index (which essentially become a UNION anyway)? Would it not do a full table scan? Don't know, will check later.

Comment: And the answer is - Yes, MySQL is smart enough to use the primary key anyway. Just checked. So, this is really the optimal solution!